# What is the common word used among programmers for a bug?

Tags: translation

What is the translation for a computer bug that is being commonly used in the programming environment?

Comment: Just let you know, often, although not always, this word is not translated.

Comment: Sometimes we call them 臭虫, but I don't think it's a standard term and I don't know how ubiquitous it is. And as others have said, usually it's not translated.

Answer (score 3):

Among Chinese users, especially programmers, it's common to informally use the English word "Bug". Often capitalised as "BUG".

See for example this blog post: [软件 Bug 引发的十次严重后果](http://blog.jobbole.com/97/)

See also: https://baike.baidu.com/item/bug/32708

Answer (score 2):

[程序错误](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E9%94%99%E8%AF%AF)

> 程序错误（英语：Bug），是程序设计中的术语，是指在软件运行中因为程序本身有错误而造成的功能不正常、死机、数据丢失、非正常中断等现象。有些程序错误会造成计算机安全隐患，此时叫做漏洞。

Comment: In real usage 程序错误 is a general program error that could be caused by network or server outage, faulty hard drive or graphic card, wrong input by the user, or in the less likely occasion, a bug.

Answer (score 1):

问题, 故障，毛病 can also be used for this. E.g. 这程序有很多问题。软件出了故障。 这程序写得有毛病。我们无法确定是软件问题还是硬件问题。

"软件有bug" is "软件有问题".